# What is the growth rate of the number of unoriented cobordism classes?

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, asymptotics, partitions, cobordism

Let $\Omega_n^O$ denote the abelian group of cobordism classes of closed, unoriented manifolds of dimension $n$, and let $d(n) := \lvert\Omega_n^O\rvert$. What are the asymptotics of $d(n)$?

It's possible to express $\log_2 d(n)$ as a modified partition function: by work of Thom, $\Omega_n^O$ is an $\mathbb F_2$-vector space with a basis of the form
$$\{x_{\ell_1,\dotsc,\ell_j}\mid \ell_1 + \dotsb + \ell_j = n, \ell_i \ne 2^r - 1\},\qquad\qquad (*)$$
so $\dim_{\mathbb F_2}\Omega_n^O = \log_2 d(n)$ is equal to the number of partitions of $n$ into numbers that are not one less than a power of 2. Hence if $P(n)$ denotes the usual partition function, $d(n) = O(2^{P(n)})$. Is this sharp? What about lower bounds?

Comment: The partitions you describe are counted in the OEIS by sequence A078657.  I just added that partition interpretation to the sequence entry.  You might want to add another comment to https://oeis.org/A078657 about the sequence matching $\log_2 d(n)$ and the appropriate Thom reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you denote by $P'(n)$ the number of partitions of $n$ with parts not of the form $2^k-1$, it holds that
$$\log P'(n)\sim \pi \sqrt{\frac{2n}{3}}$$
just like for the usual partition function. This will be true whenever you allow the parts to come from a set of integers of asymptotic density 1. See for example Nathanson's paper: ["Asymptotic density and the asymptotics of partition functions"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0002103).